# How can I close this web part using Javascript?

Tags: 2010, web-part, development

I'm trying on my site's homepage to close a web part programmatically using Javascript. The code fires, but the web part doesn't close. How can I close the web part programmatically?

```
var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext('/');
var oFile = clientContext.get_web().getFileByServerRelativeUrl('/default.aspx');
var limitedWebPartManager = oFile.getLimitedWebPartManager(SP.WebParts.PersonalizationScope.user);
var webParts = limitedWebPartManager.get_webParts();
var webPartDefinition = webParts.getById(webPartGuid);
webPartDefinition.closeWebPart(); // webPartDefinition.deleteWebPart();
clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onRemoveSucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onRemoveFailed));
```

Known:

- The same code works for *deleting* the web part (substitute deleteWebPart() for closeWebPart())
- webPartGuid is known before the code fires (again: delete succeeds w/o problem)
- onRemoveSucceeded *is* getting called when I'm trying to close, but the web part is still open

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where `webPartDiv` is the jQuery object of the web part's `<div>` having the 'WebPartID' attribute:

```
function CloseWebPart(webPartDiv) {
    var webPartHtmlDomObject = GetHtmlDomObjectFromJqueryObject(webPartDiv);
    MSOLayout_RemoveWebPart(webPartHtmlDomObject);
}

function GetHtmlDomObjectFromJqueryObject(jQueryObject) {
    var result = jQueryObject.get(0);
    return result;
}
```

`MSOLayout_RemoveWebPart` lives in the SharePoint JS files.

Answer (score 0):

After you've closed the webpart, call `webPartDefinition.saveWebPartChanges();` before proceeding with the query exectution.

```
 webPartDefinition.closeWebPart();
 webPartDefinition.saveWebPartChanges(); // add this line
 clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onRemoveSucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onRemoveFailed));
```

That worked for me.